# Making a <td> or div's into an image

Tags: html, css

I have no idea where to look for an answer to this, therefore i am posting here.

So i got a simple html code with hardcoded css into it and some php which outputs numbers (see image):

```
<td style="vertical-align: top; width:50%">
    <span>
    <img src="/wp-content/themes/ateo/img/room_measurements.png" style="width:260px; margin-left: auto; display: block;" />
    </span>
    <span style="margin-top: -110px;display: block;margin-bottom: 60px;text-align: right;margin-right: 260px;">
    <?php echo $rooms[$i]['height'] ?> m.
    </span>
    <span style="display: block;margin-top: -140px;margin-right: 150px;text-align: right;margin-bottom: 90px;transform: rotate(-18deg);">
    <?php echo $rooms[$i]['length'] ?> m.
    </span>
    <span style="margin-top: -125px;display: block;margin-left: 260px;transform: rotate(30deg);margin-bottom: 95px;">
    <?php echo $rooms[$i]['width'] ?> m.
    </span>
    </td>
```

This outputs the following (this is a screenshot - therefore the numbers are in the image):

http://tinypic.com/r/mhbnko/8

Is there anyway whatsoever to make either the td or a div tag into an image, so that when the page is loaded, the user would be able to right-click on the image, and save it with the measurements?

As it is now, the measurements is text, and therefore not saved if a person right-clicks on the image and saves it.

Regards,
Patrick

Comment: No, only if the numbers are hardcoded on the image (like suggested in the lpg's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A save to image option is not possible using standard HTML. Unless all your users downloaded some kind of browser extension that did that. There are a few other options that may work for you:

1. You could instead output in SVG and allow the user to download that.
   Most users will not be able to use SVG as an image easily though.
2. You could build the image, including measurements, on the
   server-side in PHP and then just use that in an img tag.
3. You can use Javascript and the `<canvas>` element to combine the
   image & text in the web browser. You can then use the canvas'
   `.toDataURL()` function to let the user download it as a png.

I'd recommend the last option if you can. There are many tutorials on this and the canvas element is well suited for it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `imagettftext` function to write on you image (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php). E.g.;

```
<?php
// Set the enviroment variable for GD
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));

// Create from png image
$im = imagecreatefrompng("/wp-content/themes/ateo/img/room_measurements.png");

// Create some colors
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

$height = $rooms[$i]['height']; // 8
$length = $rooms[$i]['length ']; // 10
$width = $rooms[$i]['width']; // 5

imagettftext($im, 14, 0, 10, 120, $black, $font, $height." m.");
imagettftext($im, 14, 18, 130, 45, $black, $font, $length." m.");
imagettftext($im, 14, -30, 320, 30, $black, $font, $width." m.");

// Save the file with the measures
imagepng($im,"/wp-content/themes/ateo/img/room_measurements_values.png");
?>
```

Given that you already have a php page, maybe this would be the easiest solution...